# How shall I create a single partition on a disk for making it an external hard drive with a ntfs filesytem?

Tags: partition, parted

In manpage of `parted`:

> Command: `mkpart [part-type fs-type name] start end`
>
> Creates a new partition, without creating a new file system on that
>   partition. This is useful for creating partitions for file systems (or
>   LVM, etc.) that Parted doesn’t support. You may specify a file system
>   type, to set the appropriate partition code in the partition table for
>   the new partition. fs-type is required for data partitions (i.e.,
>   non-extended partitions). start and end are the offset from the
>   beginning of the disk, that is, the “distance” from the start of the
>   disk. part-type is one of ‘primary’, ‘extended’ or ‘logical’, and may
>   be specified only with ‘msdos’ or ‘dvh’ partition tables. A name must
>   be specified for a ‘gpt’ partition table. Neither part-type nor name
>   may be used with a ‘sun’ partition table. fs-type must be one of these
>   supported file systems:
>
> ```
> ext2
> fat16, fat32
> hfs, hfs+, hfsx
> linux-swap
> NTFS
> reiserfs
> ufs
> btrfs
> ```

I have removed all the partitions on a disk by `rm` command of `parted`.

I would like to create a partition spanning as much as possible space of the disk. How can I specify its start and end? Do I need to start after a few first sectors of the disk, and how can I specify the end so that there is no unallocated space at the end?

The quote says `mkpart` doesn't create a new filesystem. If I specify `fs-type` argument to it, will it still not create a new filesystem? What is the purpose of argument `fs-type` then?

I heard that [ntfs filesystem type is the best choice if the external hard drive is to be used between Windows and Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/239320/which-file-system-do-i-select-for-sharing-files-between-windows-and-ubuntu). Is it still the case?

What requirements are on `name` argument?

Shall I choose `gpt` over other partition types?

In summary,  what is the command that I shall run? Is it

```
mkpart gpt ntfs myhdd 0
```

?

My gparted sometimes runs very slow, so I am learning to use parted to do the task, which is very simple in this case.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a full-disk partition on a GPT disk with these commands. I have a slightly extended version of `pdisk` as a standard utility on most of my systems.

```
# Create a simple function pdisk to hide some of the complexity of parted
pdisk() {
    local dsk="$1"; shift; [[ $# -eq 0 ]] && set -- print;
    parted "$dsk" --align optimal unit MiB "$@";
}

# We are going to DESTROY and REFORMAT /dev/sdz. Change to suit your removable disk
dsk=/dev/sdz

pdisk "$dsk" mklabel gpt                   # GPT disk label (you may get asked for confirmation)
pdisk "$dsk" mkpart primary ntfs 1 100%    # Create a single partition for the entire disk
pdisk "$dsk"                               # Show what we have done

partprobe "$dsk"                           # Generate the partition devices
mkfs -t ntfs "${dsk}"*1                    # Format partition 1 as NTFS (if you must)
```

If you want to experiment safely, without breaking a real disk, use a temporary file on your disk like this instead of the brazen `dsk=/dev/sdz` above.

```
dd if=/dev/zero bs=1M count=100 >100m.img  # Create 100MB "disk" image
dsk=$(losetup --show --find 100m.img)      # Associate a loopback device
echo "$dsk"                                # Report what it is called
```

Then, when you have finished,

```
losetup -d "$dsk"                          # Disassociate the loopback device(s)
rm "$dsk"                                  # You know
```

Comment: Thanks. The quote says mkpart doesn't create a new filesystem. If I specify fs-type argument to it, will it still not create a new filesystem? What is the purpose of argument fs-type then?

Comment: It's a convenience so you can declare what the partition's holding. Mostly it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Thanks. The manpage says "part-type is one of ‘primary’, ‘extended’ or ‘logical’, and may be specified only with ‘msdos’ or ‘dvh’ partition tables." Here since you specify gpt, is specifying primary necessary (and working)?

Comment: Works for me. I've just re-tested with a loop device (`dd if=/dev/zero bs=1M count=100 >100m.img; dsk=$(losetup --show --find 100m.img); echo "$dsk"`)

Comment: In concept,  does specifying primary for gpt make sense? (I am not sure)

Comment: Honestly? I don't know. It was in the documentation - as I understood it - when I first started using `parted` for GPT disks.